# Regular expression for the email address

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like below:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5}$
```

My question is how do I not allow `@gmail.com` from my above regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular-expression to restrict email address domains - you'll end-up complicating the expression and when it fails to match you won't know if it's because the email address is invalid or if it's because of the gmail mention.

If an email address matches the regex, then you can safely check if it ends with "@gmail.com":

```
Regex emailRegex = ...
if( emailRegex.IsMatch( email ) ) {
    if( !email.EndsWith("@gmail.com") ) {
        // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere and saved this thing called [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It's like this:
'^/(?!ignoreme|ignoreme2|ignoremeN)$'